# I need help with my custom mob command!

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I have this command here. It's supposed to spawn a wither skeleton with a custom head and some gear.

```
Errors: "Data Parsing Failed: Unbalanced curly brackets"
```

Command:

```
/summon Skeleton ~0 ~1 ~0 {Equipment:[{id:iron_sword,tag:{Unbreakable:1,ench:[{id:19,lvl:2},
{id:16,lvl:1}]}},{},{},{},{id:skull,Damage:3,
tag:SkullOwner:{Id:"5ee854b8-0f30-4ca6-8039-3c0cd74c7d42",Properties:{textures:
[{Value:"eyJ0ZXh0dXJlcyI6eyJTS0lOIjp7InVybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly90ZXh0dXJlcy5taW5lY3JhZnQubmV0L3RleHR1cmUvMTk3ZjI4NmRmZTg3YzkyY2VhMjkyODgxNTcxZTgyNjEyNTg2NDM4Y2FiNWMwZjg0N2ZmZTBjOTFhYjlkYmUxIn19fQ=="}]}}},
CustomName:Golem,CustomNameVisible:1,Attributes:[{Name:generic.maxHealth,Base:30},
{Name:generic.movementSpeed,Base:0.7},{Name:generic.followRange,Base:40},
{Name:generic.knockbackResistance,Base:1}],
ActiveEffects:[{Id:10,Amplifier:1,Duration:999999}],SkeletonType:1}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I fix "unbalanced brackets" in my data tag?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/265668/how-can-i-fix-unbalanced-brackets-in-my-data-tag)

Answer (score 1):

Your curly braces appear to be fine.  But by the looks of it, you are missing a closing square bracket (`]`) in your `Equipment` element (array).

Try putting one at the end of the `Equipment` element (after the textures value), before the comma:

```
Equipment:[{id:iron_sword,tag:{Unbreakable:1,ench:[{id:19,lvl:2},
{id:16,lvl:1}]}},{},{},{},{id:skull,Damage:3,tag:SkullOwner:
{Id:"5ee854b8-0f30-4ca6-8039-3c0cd74c7d42",Properties:{textures:
[{Value:"eyJ0ZXh0dXJlcyI6eyJTS0lOIjp7InVybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly90ZXh0dXJlcy5taW5lY3JhZnQubmV0L3RleHR1cmUvMTk3ZjI4NmRmZTg3YzkyY2VhMjkyODgxNTcxZTgyNjEyNTg2NDM4Y2FiNWMwZjg0N2ZmZTBjOTFhYjlkYmUxIn19fQ=="}]
}}}],CustomName:Golem
```

Just a thought, but if you're having trouble scripting commands like this, it helps to paste them into a text editor like [Atom](https://atom.io).  Tools like that make it **much** easier to see opening/closing brackets and braces.

[image]

Also, the [Minecraft mobspawner and summon generator](http://minecraft.tools/en/spawn.php) tool can help you with the correct syntax as well.

Comment: It still doesn't work :/ new error: Data parsing failed: unable to locate name/value sepatator for string: {},{},{},{id:skull,Damage:3,
tag:SkullOwner:{Id:"5ee854b8-0f30-4ca6-8039-...

Comment: @ConnorHayes Just to verify, you put the `]` in this part of your code, right?: `9fQ=="}]}}}],
CustomName:Golem`

Comment: I did place the bracket yes

Comment: @ConnorHayes Just a thought, but try putting that `]` just inside the last `}` instead.  Otherwise, checkout the Minecraft Mobspawner and Summon Generator tool that I posted a link to.  When I try to match-up the options available for a "Skeleton" to the properties you have specified, the code comes out somewhat different.  Might be worth taking a look at.